# PySpark select Row Where column equals parameter value in current row

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a data frame that has a current date value I create a new column in the data frame that calculates one month ago like so,

```
 spark_df = spark_df.withColumn("oneMonthAgo", expr("add_months(calendarday, -1)"))
```

I would like to go back and find the row that has the AsofDate that matches that oneMonthAgo column and include its value as a new column called 1MonthAgoValue.  Origninaly I was trying to use window functions to go back but because no oneMonthAgo column matches dates it would return its own value in the 1MonthAgoValue column.

```
 Beginning Data Frame
 +----------+-----------+-----------+

 |  AsofDate|oneMonthAgo|      value|

 +----------+-----------+-----------+

 |2019-02-23| 2019-02-20|          2|

 |2019-03-20| 2019-02-20|          7|

 |2019-03-21| 2019-02-21|         12|

 |2019-03-22| 2019-02-22|         27|

 |2019-03-23| 2019-02-23|         91|

 +----------+-----------+-----------+


 Data Frame to end up with
 +----------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+

 |  AsofDate|oneMonthAgo|      value|         1MonthAgoValue|

 +----------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+

 |2019-02-23| 2019-02-20|          2|                  null |

 |2019-03-20| 2019-02-20|          7|                  null |

 |2019-03-21| 2019-02-21|         12|                  null |

 |2019-03-22| 2019-02-22|         27|                  null |

 |2019-03-23| 2019-02-23|         91|                     2 |  (oneMonthAgo matches first rows AsofDate include first rows value column in current row as 1MonthAgoValue )

 +----------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+



 +---------------+-----------------------+-----------+--------------+-----+-------+----+------------+--------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
  |accountname|             calendarday|     market|returnposition| year| month| day|yearUnique|last_monday|firstDayOfMonth|oneMonthAgo|twoMonthAgo| threeMonthAgo| sixMonthAgo|twelveMonthAgo|                       indexCP|inceptionDate| 
 +--------------+-----------------------+-----------+--------------+-----+-------+----+------------+--------------+------------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
  |          Giants|2015-01-02 00:00:00|           null|               null| 2015|       01|   02|2015-01-02| 2014-12-29|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-02|      2014-11-02|      2014-10-02|    2014-07-02|         2014-01-02|                           100.0|    2015-01-02|
  |          Giants|2015-01-05 00:00:00|110086.25|         0.0105| 2015|       01|   05|2015-01-05| 2015-01-05|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-05|      2014-11-05|      2014-10-05|    2014-07-05|         2014-01-05|                         101.05|    2015-01-02|
  |          Giants|2015-01-06 00:00:00|  201251.5|         2.0E-4| 2015|       01|   06|2015-01-06| 2015-01-05|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-06|      2014-11-06|      2014-10-06|    2014-07-06|         2014-01-06|  101.07020999999999|   2015-01-02|
  |          Giants|2015-01-07 00:00:00|  216786.5|         -0.006| 2015|       01|   07|2015-01-07| 2015-01-05|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-07|      2014-11-07|      2014-10-07|    2014-07-07|         2014-01-07|              100.46378874|    2015-01-02|
  |          Giants|2015-01-08 00:00:00|  215464.5|       -0.0063| 2015|       01|   08|2015-01-08| 2015-01-05|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-08|      2014-11-08|      2014-10-08|    2014-07-08|         2014-01-08|        99.830866870938|    2015-01-02|
  |          Giants|2015-01-09 00:00:00|214103.25|        0.0052| 2015|       01|   09|2015-01-09| 2015-01-05|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-09|      2014-11-09|      2014-10-09|    2014-07-09|         2014-01-09|  100.34998737866687|    2015-01-02|
  |          Giants|2015-01-12 00:00:00|  215218.5|       -4.0E-4| 2015|       01|   12|2015-01-12| 2015-01-12|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-12|      2014-11-12|      2014-10-12|    2014-07-12|         2014-01-12|  100.30984738371541|    2015-01-02|
  |          Giants|2015-01-13 00:00:00|215125.25|        0.0036| 2015|       01|   13|2015-01-13| 2015-01-12|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-13|      2014-11-13|      2014-10-13|    2014-07-13|         2014-01-13|  100.67096283429677|    2015-01-02|
  |          Giants|2015-01-14 00:00:00|  215919.5|        8.0E-4| 2015|       01|   14|2015-01-14| 2015-01-12|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-14|      2014-11-14|      2014-10-14|    2014-07-14|         2014-01-14|    100.7514996045642|    2015-01-02|
  |          Giants|2015-01-15 00:00:00|216103.75|        4.0E-4| 2015|       01|   15|2015-01-15| 2015-01-12|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-15|      2014-11-15|      2014-10-15|    2014-07-15|         2014-01-15|  100.79180020440602|    2015-01-02|
  |          Giants|2015-01-16 00:00:00|  216205.5|       0.0052| 2015|       01|   16|2015-01-16| 2015-01-12|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-16|      2014-11-16|      2014-10-16|    2014-07-16|         2014-01-16|  101.31591756546894|    2015-01-02|
  |          Giants|2015-01-19 00:00:00|  347334.0|      -0.0045| 2015|       01|   19|2015-01-19| 2015-01-19|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-19|      2014-11-19|      2014-10-19|    2014-07-19|         2014-01-19|  100.85999593642434|    2015-01-02|
  |          Giants|2015-01-20 00:00:00|  345767.0|       0.0015| 2015|       01|   20|2015-01-20| 2015-01-19|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-20|      2014-11-20|      2014-10-20|    2014-07-20|         2014-01-20|  101.01128593032898|    2015-01-02|
  |          Giants|2015-01-21 00:00:00|  346314.5|       2.0E-4| 2015|       01|   21|2015-01-21| 2015-01-19|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-21|      2014-11-21|      2014-10-21|    2014-07-21|         2014-01-21|  101.03148818751504|    2015-01-02|
  |          Giants|2015-01-22 00:00:00|346399.75|       0.0029| 2015|       01|   22|2015-01-22| 2015-01-19|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-22|      2014-11-22|      2014-10-22|    2014-07-22|         2014-01-22| 101.32447950325883|    2015-01-02|
  |          Giants|2015-01-23 00:00:00|347412.75|      -6.0E-4| 2015|       01|   23|2015-01-23| 2015-01-19|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-23|      2014-11-23|      2014-10-23|    2014-07-23|         2014-01-23| 101.26368481555686|    2015-01-02|
  |          Giants|2015-01-26 00:00:00|348303.75|      -6.0E-4| 2015|       01|   26|2015-01-26| 2015-01-26|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-26|      2014-11-26|      2014-10-26|    2014-07-26|         2014-01-26| 101.20292660466752|    2015-01-02|
  |          Giants|2015-01-27 00:00:00|  348541.0|      -0.0044| 2015|       01|   27|2015-01-27| 2015-01-26|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-27|      2014-11-27|      2014-10-27|    2014-07-27|         2014-01-27| 100.75763372760697|    2015-01-02|
  |          Giants|2015-01-28 00:00:00|347579.25|       0.0015| 2015|       01|   28|2015-01-28| 2015-01-26|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-28|      2014-11-28|      2014-10-28|    2014-07-28|         2014-01-28|   100.9087701781984|    2015-01-02|
  |          Giants|2015-01-29 00:00:00|348431.75|       2.0E-4| 2015|       01|   29|2015-01-29| 2015-01-26|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-29|      2014-11-29|      2014-10-29|    2014-07-29|         2014-01-29|  100.92895193223403|    2015-01-02|
  |        Yankees|2015-01-02 00:00:00|           null|               null| 2015|       01|   02|2015-01-02| 2014-12-29|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-02|      2014-11-02|      2014-10-02|    2014-07-02|         2014-01-02|                           100.0|    2015-01-02|
  |        Yankees|2015-01-05 00:00:00|110086.25|         0.0105| 2015|       01|   05|2015-01-05| 2015-01-05|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-05|      2014-11-05|      2014-10-05|    2014-07-05|         2014-01-05|                         101.05|    2015-01-02|
  |        Yankees|2015-01-06 00:00:00|  201251.5|         2.0E-4| 2015|       01|   06|2015-01-06| 2015-01-05|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-06|      2014-11-06|      2014-10-06|    2014-07-06|         2014-01-06|  101.07020999999999|   2015-01-02|
  |        Yankees|2015-01-07 00:00:00|  216786.5|         -0.006| 2015|       01|   07|2015-01-07| 2015-01-05|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-07|      2014-11-07|      2014-10-07|    2014-07-07|         2014-01-07|              100.46378874|    2015-01-02|
  |        Yankees|2015-01-08 00:00:00|  215464.5|       -0.0063| 2015|       01|   08|2015-01-08| 2015-01-05|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-08|      2014-11-08|      2014-10-08|    2014-07-08|         2014-01-08|        99.830866870938|    2015-01-02|
  |        Yankees|2015-01-09 00:00:00|214103.25|        0.0052| 2015|       01|   09|2015-01-09| 2015-01-05|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-09|      2014-11-09|      2014-10-09|    2014-07-09|         2014-01-09|  100.34998737866687|    2015-01-02|
  |        Yankees|2015-01-12 00:00:00|  215218.5|       -4.0E-4| 2015|       01|   12|2015-01-12| 2015-01-12|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-12|      2014-11-12|      2014-10-12|    2014-07-12|         2014-01-12|  100.30984738371541|    2015-01-02|
  |        Yankees|2015-01-13 00:00:00|215125.25|        0.0036| 2015|       01|   13|2015-01-13| 2015-01-12|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-13|      2014-11-13|      2014-10-13|    2014-07-13|         2014-01-13|  100.67096283429677|    2015-01-02|
  |        Yankees|2015-01-14 00:00:00|  215919.5|        8.0E-4| 2015|       01|   14|2015-01-14| 2015-01-12|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-14|      2014-11-14|      2014-10-14|    2014-07-14|         2014-01-14|    100.7514996045642|    2015-01-02|
  |        Yankees|2015-01-15 00:00:00|216103.75|        4.0E-4| 2015|       01|   15|2015-01-15| 2015-01-12|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-15|      2014-11-15|      2014-10-15|    2014-07-15|         2014-01-15|  100.79180020440602|    2015-01-02|
  |        Yankees|2015-01-16 00:00:00|  216205.5|       0.0052| 2015|       01|   16|2015-01-16| 2015-01-12|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-16|      2014-11-16|      2014-10-16|    2014-07-16|         2014-01-16|  101.31591756546894|    2015-01-02|
  |        Yankees|2015-01-19 00:00:00|  347334.0|      -0.0045| 2015|       01|   19|2015-01-19| 2015-01-19|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-19|      2014-11-19|      2014-10-19|    2014-07-19|         2014-01-19|  100.85999593642434|    2015-01-02|
  |        Yankees|2015-01-20 00:00:00|  345767.0|       0.0015| 2015|       01|   20|2015-01-20| 2015-01-19|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-20|      2014-11-20|      2014-10-20|    2014-07-20|         2014-01-20|  101.01128593032898|    2015-01-02|
  |        Yankees|2015-01-21 00:00:00|  346314.5|       2.0E-4| 2015|       01|   21|2015-01-21| 2015-01-19|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-21|      2014-11-21|      2014-10-21|    2014-07-21|         2014-01-21|  101.03148818751504|    2015-01-02|
  |        Yankees|2015-01-22 00:00:00|346399.75|       0.0029| 2015|       01|   22|2015-01-22| 2015-01-19|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-22|      2014-11-22|      2014-10-22|    2014-07-22|         2014-01-22| 101.32447950325883|    2015-01-02|
  |        Yankees|2015-01-23 00:00:00|347412.75|      -6.0E-4| 2015|       01|   23|2015-01-23| 2015-01-19|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-23|      2014-11-23|      2014-10-23|    2014-07-23|         2014-01-23| 101.26368481555686|    2015-01-02|
  |        Yankees|2015-01-26 00:00:00|348303.75|      -6.0E-4| 2015|       01|   26|2015-01-26| 2015-01-26|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-26|      2014-11-26|      2014-10-26|    2014-07-26|         2014-01-26| 101.20292660466752|    2015-01-02|
  |        Yankees|2015-01-27 00:00:00|  348541.0|      -0.0044| 2015|       01|   27|2015-01-27| 2015-01-26|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-27|      2014-11-27|      2014-10-27|    2014-07-27|         2014-01-27| 100.75763372760697|    2015-01-02|
  |        Yankees|2015-01-28 00:00:00|347579.25|       0.0015| 2015|       01|   28|2015-01-28| 2015-01-26|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-28|      2014-11-28|      2014-10-28|    2014-07-28|         2014-01-28|   100.9087701781984|    2015-01-02|
  |        Yankees|2015-01-29 00:00:00|348431.75|       2.0E-4| 2015|       01|   29|2015-01-29| 2015-01-26|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-29|      2014-11-29|      2014-10-29|    2014-07-29|         2014-01-29|  100.92895193223403|    2015-01-02|
  |        Yankees|2015-02-28 00:00:00|348431.75|       2.0E-4| 2015|       02|   28|2015-02-28| 2015-01-26|        2015-01-01|   2014-12-28|      2014-11-28|      2014-10-28|    2014-07-28|         2014-01-28|  100.92895193223403|    2015-01-02|
 +--------------+-----------------------+-----------+--------------+-----+-------+----+------------+--------------+------------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a **`left_outer self join`** like this.

```
from pyspark.sql import function as F
df.join(df.select(F.col("AsofDate").alias("oneMonthAgo"),\
                  F.col("value").alias("1MonthAgoValue")),['oneMonthAgo'],'left_outer')\
  .orderBy("AsofDate")\
  .show()

#+-----------+----------+-----+--------------+
#|oneMonthAgo|  AsofDate|value|1MonthAgoValue|
#+-----------+----------+-----+--------------+
#| 2019-02-20|2019-02-23|    2|          null|
#| 2019-02-20|2019-03-20|    7|          null|
#| 2019-02-21|2019-03-21|   12|          null|
#| 2019-02-22|2019-03-22|   27|          null|
#| 2019-02-23|2019-03-23|   91|             2|
#+-----------+----------+-----+--------------+
```

**`UPDATE:`**

Try this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w=Window().partitionBy(F.dayofmonth("AsofDate"))\
          .orderBy(F.to_timestamp("AsofDate").cast("long"))\
          .rangeBetween(86400*-30,0)

first=F.first("value").over(w)

df.withColumn("1MonthAgoValue", F.when(first!=F.col("value"), first)\
                                 .otherwise(F.lit(None))).show()
```

Comment: so that seems to have made my output file 10x larger and multiple rows are repeating themself.  I will play around with it a little more but I do think this is the right path. Thanks!

Comment: U could try using .distinct() or drop_duplicates using a subset of columns.

Comment: i think it is because there are multiple reoccurring AsofDate in my data were there is a idValue that is different per AsofDate.  I think i can edit the orderBy to include two values to solve the issue.

Comment: I’m not sure if that will resolve the issue, if you could provide a sample of the data after self join (including ur Id column) I’d be happy to suggest something

Comment: i updated it with a full data set.  Is there a way to do this with sql? like select previous row where AsofDate == oneMonthAgo and put it into a variable to use?

Comment: or the ability to select a specific row from a window fucntion where AsofDate == a specific value (oneMonthAgo)? something like this `wz3 = Window.partitionBy('accountname')   
spark_df = spark_df.withColumn('PreviousMonthUniqueoneMonthAgo', ("yearUnique").over(wz3).where(col('yearUnique') == spark_df['oneMonthAgo']))`

Comment: try my update n @Dee 's solution n see what works best for u

Comment: it looks like Dee's answer didnt work as it was always just pulling the first date within the month instead of the 30 days ago.  Your answer worked for the most part but the hardcoded -30 means that if a previous month ago falls on a weekend it returns null.  I went back to your first method and played with it a bunch and got something thats working.  Only problem is that it is dropping rows where it cant find matching rows.  Anyway to stop it from doing that?

Comment: found it looks like doing it as a leftouter join seems to be working

Comment: that should preserve the non matches. ill edit in my solution too

Comment: Thanks again your have been a huge help!  I am sure I will get stuck on something again in the next 3 days and be back.

Answer (score 2):

This will work, a window function was the right way to go about it but you don't need the AsofDate col for this

```
from pyspark.sql import function as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy(F.dayofmonth('AsofDate'))
w = w.orderBy(F.Year('AsofDate'),F.month('AsofDate'))

df.withColumn('1MonthAgoValue', F.lag('value').over(w))
```

In a real dataset you might want to make it more unique and do this by id/for every id, if that's the case add the id col to the partitionBy too.

PS: if lag() gets you the wrong result use lead() I always forget the order and end up having to try both.

Comment: nice one! only thing is i don't think it will work if data has multiple years

Comment: Cheers. Ah didn't think of that as there's only a year in the data, updated the answer that should work